# Mathematica crashes with a simple For-loop

Tags: crash, infinite-loop

I am new to Mathematica, so I am sorry if this is a bit of a stupid question but I really am stumped.

I am trying to define a function in Mathematica that does a very specific thing, but for some reason Mathematica keeps crashing while testing it. After messing around a bit I have found where the problem lies: when trying to evaluate a simple `For` loop Mathematica keeps crashing (to the point where I have to force close it with Task Manager). See the image below:

[image: screenshot]

`vectorBasis` is a function defined below. As you can see, `Length[vectorBasis[perm]]` is simply the number 3, so I really feel like the `For`-loop should print the numbers 1, 2, and 3. But this completely crashes Mathematica.

Can anyone explain to me why this happens and how I can avoid it? Thanks!

Edit: Someone asked for a copy paste-able code, so here it is:

```
perm = {2,3,4}
vectorBasis[perm]
Length[vectorBasis[perm]]
For[i = 1, i <= Length[vectorBasis[perm]], i++, Print[i]]
```

The reason that I hadn't included it is that for this to be evaluate-able you need the function `vectorBasis`, which relies on functions from the [amplituhedronBoundaries package](https://github.com/mrmrob003/amplituhedronBoundaries) ([paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.07146.pdf)). The definitions might be a bit convoluted, but they seem to work:

```
<<amplituhedronBoundaries`

arrayToVec[array_, dimension_] := Module[{EmptyVec = ConstantArray[0, dimension]}, For[i = 1, i <= Length[array], i++, EmptyVec = placePart[EmptyVec, array[[i]] -> 1]]; EmptyVec]

vectorBasis[permutation_] := arrayToVec[#, Length[permutation]] & /@ hypBasis[topCell[Length[permutation], permK[permutation]]]
```

where `hypBasis`, `topCell` and `permK` are defined in the package I linked above.

Comment: Please post a copy-pastable form of the code rather than an image.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but learning Mathematica and using `For` loops are usually mutually exclusive undertakings ;) There are much better ways that you should learn.

Comment: Staples, can you, please, provide a code snippet to acquire & load the package these functions are dependent upon? It will make this question much better for future users & for those who wish to try to answer.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you end up in an infinite loop is that you are reusing `i` as iteration variable. After executing `vectorBasis[perm]`, `arrayToVec` has set `i` to $2$. Therefore, every time the condition `i <= Length[vectorBasis[perm]]` is checked, `i` is reset to $2$, and the condition will always be satisfied. An easy fix would be to make `i` in `arrayToVec` a local variable, i.e.

```
arrayToVec[array_, dimension_] := 
Module[{EmptyVec = ConstantArray[0, dimension],i}, 
    For[i = 1, i <= Length[array], i++, 
        EmptyVec = ReplacePart[EmptyVec, array[[i]] -> 1]]; 
    EmptyVec
]
```

As @J.M. suggests, a `Do` loop would be a better fit for the job

```
arrayToVec[array_, dimension_] := 
Module[{EmptyVec = ConstantArray[0, dimension]}, 
   Do[EmptyVec = ReplacePart[EmptyVec, array[[i]] -> 1], {i, Length[array]}] 
   EmptyVec
]
```

More compact versions without loops would be

```
arrayToVec[array_, dimension_] := 
    ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0,dimension],#->1&/@array]

arrayToVec[array_, dimension_] := 
    Sum[UnitVector[dimension,i],{i,array}]
```

Also, in case someone wants to reproduce this, the `` positroids` ``  package is required, which is bundled with the arXiv preprint [1212.6974](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6974) (this defines for example `` Global`permK[perm] ``).

Comment: I would even go further and suggest that `Do[]` should replace `For[]` here.